# Semigroup algebras with one dimensional center

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $S$ be a finite semigroup and $K$ a field of characteristic 0 (we can assume the complex numbers for simplicity).

> Question: Is there a characterization when the center of the semigroup algebra $KS$ is one-dimensional and a  basis is given by the idendity of $KS$ (meaning $KS$ has an identity)?

If it helps, we can assume that $S$ is a band, meaning that $x^2=x$ for all $x \in S$.

Having trivial center seems to be rare but there are still many examples.
Here the number of semigroups with trivial center with $n \geq 2$ elements for small $n$:
0,5,9,251,1478.

Here the number of bands with trivial center with $n \geq 2$ elements for small $n$:
0,3,4,49,142.

Comment: Centers of semigroup algebras are a pain to compute. For bands which are monoids (but it should be the same if the algebra is unital) we know how to compute the quiver and it can be connected but doesn't have to be. There is an algorithm to do this for bands

Comment: I believe if you adjoin a zero to a left zero semigroup you get a one dimensional center without having a unit.  The zero should span the center.

Comment: Small pet peeve: groups are G and semigroups are S :)

Comment: If you take a finite quiver and look at the semigroup of all nonempty paths modulo making all paths of length n or greater 0 with n>1, you will get a semigroup algebra with 1 dimensional center.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Thanks I edited the question. Yes, acyclic quiver algebras have 1-dimensional center. The question is partially motivated to see when semigroup algebras are acyclic quiver algebras. Does the algorithm for bands even calculate the quivers and relations or just the quiver?

Comment: In general just the quiver but sometimes the relations.  They don't have to be acyclic.

Comment: There isn't a simple characterization of when a semigroup algebra is unital

Comment: You can find a band whose quiver is the two cycle and relations is one of the paths of length 2 is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer what goes on with bands.    I'll assume the band is a monoid for simplicity.  I think everything works so long as the band is unital but this can get messier to describe.  Details of what I'm saying can be found in [Margolis, S., & Steinberg, B. (2012). Quivers of monoids with basic algebras. Compositio Mathematica, 148(5), 1516-1560.](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/compositio-mathematica/article/quivers-of-monoids-with-basic-algebras/39F94B0FF1357609C65687DBA4D307D4)  and some of our later papers.

The algebra of a band is split basic over every field so it is isomorphic to the algebra of a bound quiver.

A left regular band is a semigroup satisfying the identities $x^2=x, xyx=xy$.   These identities say that repetition is useless.  For monoids, the first identity is a consequence of the second.  Left regular bands are precisely the bands $S$ for which $aS=bS$ implies $a=b$ (so left divisibility is an order). Therefore, a left regular band is ordered by $a\leq b\iff aS\subseteq bS\iff ba=a$.

If $M$ is a left regular band, then the principal left ideals of $M$ are closed under intersection and hence form a lattice $\Lambda(M)$.  The vertices of the quiver of $M$ (if you work with left modules) is $\Lambda(M)$.  If $Ma,Mb$ are two principal left ideals, then there are no arrows from $Ma$ to $Mb$ unless $Ma\subsetneq Mb$.  If $Ma\subsetneq Mb$, then the number of edges from $Ma$ to $Mb$ is one less than the number of connected components of the restriction of the Hasse diagram of $M$ to those elements $m\in M$ with $Ma\subseteq Mm$ and $m<b$.  So as you can see this is already a bit messy to say when you get a connected quiver.

A right regular band is defined dually: $x^2=x$ and $xyx=yx$ for all $x,y$.  The quiver of a right regular band is computed dually.  The principal right ideals form the vertices, there are no arrows $aM$ to $bM$ unless $bM\supsetneq aM$, in which case you count the number of connected components minus one of the Hasse diagram for the order $a\leq b$ if $ab=a$ of the set of $m$ with $m<b$ and $aM\subseteq mM$.

A regular band is a band satisfying $xyxzx=xyzx$.  In other words $a\mapsto xax$ is a retraction from $M$ to $xMx$.  It turns out that if $M$ is a band and $K$ is a field, then the map $M\to KM\to KM/J(KM)^2$ (where $J(KM)$ is radical) factors through a regular band $M'$ (the universal regular band image of $M$).  Hence the quiver of $KM$ and $KM'$ are the same, and so one is reduced to the case of regular bands.

Every regular band $M$ embeds in a direct product $M_l\times M_r$ where $M_l$ is a left regular band that has lattice of principal left ideals isomorphic to the lattice of principal two-sided ideals of $M$ and $M_r$ is a right regular band that has lattice of principal right ideals isomorphic to the lattice of principal two-sided ideals of $M$.  The quiver of $M$ is obtained by superimposing the quivers of $M_l$ and $M_r$ on each other (identifying their vertices via the bijections above).  So the vertices of the quiver can be identified with the two-sided principal ideals of $M$.  Arrows going up in the order are computed via the left regular band image $M_l$ and arrows going down in the order are computed via the right regular band image $M_r$.  In particular, the quiver need not be acyclic.

How you would every turn this into a simple characterization of connectedness of the quiver is beyond me.

Here is a good example.  Let $S$ be the semigroup $\{1,2\}\times \{1,2\}$ with multiplication $(i,j)(k,l)=(i,l)$.  Let $M=S\cup I$ where $I$ is an identity.  Then the quiver of $M$ has two vertices $v,w$ and edges $x\colon v\to w$ and $y\colon w\to v$.  There is a single relation $yx=0$ (where I compose paths from right to left because I do left modules).

**Added.** In a paper with Margolis and Saliola, we showed the path algebra of an acyclic quiver is always the monoid algebra of a left regular band.